# Power Query/Power Pivot - Difference of two columns

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot

I try to compare two PowerPivot columns, specifically take the difference of the two columns, but I don't get it. In a normal Pivot-Table, I can easily add a calculated field but in PowerPivot it is not possible (at least not for me).

The Pivot looks like this:
[image]

And I want to add the three difference columns, that it looks like this:
[image]

Is this even possible?

That is how my Pivot Datafield order looks like
[image]

Thank you!

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: In PowerPivot you use measures rather than calculated fields. Measures are far more powerful, but do require you to write some DAX.

Comment: I tried that already, but in my dataset, Product 1 and 2 are in the same column, so I think I have to do a sum if formula right? But: Volume is also a column, and rentability is a measure already. I have a really hard time with this pivot table... Do you maybe have an example for such an issue?

Comment: In that case it would be a calculated item, not a calculated field, in a regular pivot table. You could create a calculated column in your model table for each product value using a simple IF formula to either return the relevant field value or 0 depending on which product it is. Alternatively, I'd suggest you create a measure for Produkt1 and another for Produkt2 explicitly, then a third measure that just subtracts one from the other. You'll need to repeat that for each value field in your pivot.

Comment: Sample measure formula: `=calculate(sum([ValueFieldName]),TableName[ProductName]="Produkt1")`

Comment: One of your tags is `powerquery`.  In `powerquery` it's rather trivial to add a custom column that calculates that difference.  You don't even have to know any M-code. You can do it right from the UI.  Is that not an acceptable solution?  And yes, if you have an unknown number of column pairs, you can automate the whole process.

Comment: It is an option to solve that directly in power query. But product 1 and 2 are in the same column, so it is noch easy substracting two columns. How would you do it?

Comment: Rory, your suggestion does not work because the columns in my dataset are shown rows in the pivot table, for example: volume is a dataset column but a pivot table row, the same with DB III andi so on. Can I transpone this with Dax? I think it can work then

Comment: Please flag whoever you are responding to with `@` followed by their name, else we won't get notified.  In your posted screenshots, your products 1 and 2 seem to be in different columns. Why do you write they are in the same column?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it seems so, but in my dataset volume, DBIII and so on (pivot table rows) are columns and the other way around product 1 and 2 are rows in the dataset. I shifted values in my pivot table from rows to columns. I will add a screenshot in the post above.